# RegEx to compare two substrings within a line

Tags: regex

I have a consistently formatted lines that are essentially delimited field/value pairs and I need to use a single regex expression to compare the values of two fields and match if they are the same. I don't need the values, just the match/no match comparison. Here are two examples, the first should match the second should not.

1. @@field1@@someValue@@field2@@someValue@@otherField@@otherValue
2. @@field1@@someValue@@field2@@someDIFFERENTValue@@otherField@@otherValue

I can match any field or value on a known pattern, and I can use lookarounds to do AND operations.

But I don't know how to extract and save the value of some pattern match, like `field1@@(.*?)@@`

, and then use that "someValue" in an expression comparing it to the "contents" of `field2@@(.*?)@@`

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: How about [this](https://regex101.com/r/6kiBhi/1)? It will not work if `field name` can be equal to `some_value`.

Comment: Another way could be [`^(@@.*?@@)(.*?(?=@))(?1)(\2)`](https://regex101.com/r/6kiBhi/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
@@field1@@([^@]*)@@field2@@(?=\1@@)
@@field1@@((?:(?!@@).)*?)@@field2@@(?=\1@@)
```

Use the former if there can be no `@` in value contents. Else, use the latter regex.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VTuF9D/1/)

**Details**

- `@@field1@@` - a literal string
- `([^@]*)` - Capturing group 1 (later in the pattern, it can be referred to with `\1` backreference): any 0 or more chars other than `@`
- `@@field2@@` - a literal string
- `(?=\1@@)` - immediately to the right of the current location, there must be the same value as captured in Group 1 followed with `@@`. If end of string can occur, replace with `(?=\1(?:@@|$))`.

The `(?:(?!@@).)*?` pattern "roughly" means *any text but `@@`*, it actually matches any single char (other than a line break char), as few occurrences as possible, that does not start a `@@` char sequence.